# iText pdf Library unsupport on Android studio

Tags: android

I am doing pdf conversion by using **itextpdf-5.5.3.jar** for my application in android studio, but i got following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    E:\Android\Android Studio\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output E:\Android\Workspace_ReceiptORG\ExpenseManager\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=E:\Android\Workspace_ReceiptORG\ExpenseManager\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\libraryList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Please help me out.........

Comment: Can you update app gradle so i can get idea about dependency  ?
Also add ss of libs

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Android version of iTextPDF .

Download "itextg-5.4.3.jar"

Answer (score 0):

For UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

app gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
              multiDexEnabled true
              }
```

outer tag:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
```

If still error then you can increase heap size.

```
 android.dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries false
    }
```